# Make image responsive in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, image, responsive-images

How do I make images automatically resize themselves depending on the screen size?

I add a css attribute for an image such as

```
 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }
```

but that will make a small image take the form of the container it is in and if the container is huge, the small image will stretch out and pixelate.  So do I just create special css attribute for the large images?  I don't want the images to fill up the container or div that they are in.  I just want them to resize based on the screen size.  Tables should also resize as well.  I'm using both divs and tables.

Comment: Use img's css with media queries. read more for media query here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

Insert the image normally;

In "Size" select "Custom";

Set the "Width" and "Height" to "0";

Insert this in your CSS code:

```
img {
     border: 0 none;
     max-width: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please Refer This page [Using Media Queries with Custom CSS](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/custom-css-media-queries/)